# How to return the correlation value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a method for calculating the correlation between to columns of data from a dataset. The dataset is constructed of 4 columns A1, A2, A3, and Class. My goal is remove A3 if the correlation between A1 & A3 greater than 0.6 or if the correlation between A1 & A3 is less than 0.6.

A sample of the data set is given below:

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
```

The python program that I am using for this project is written like so

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np

def main():
    s = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    print(calculate_correlation(s))

def calculate_correlation(s):
    # if correlation > 0.6 or correlation < 0.6 remove A3
    s = s[['A1','A3']]
    return s.corr()[1,0]

main()
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\physe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: (1, 0)
```

I've reviewed the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html). The issue that I'm facing is selecting the 1,0 element from the covariance matrix that is returned by .corr().

Comment: Do you mean like `s.corr().iloc[1,0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example:

```
cor = df.corr()
if cor['A3'] > 0.6:
   train.drop(columns = 'A3', inplace = True)
else:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
corr = df.corr()
if corr['A3'].loc['A1']!=0.6:
    df.drop(columns=['A3'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .iloc to get the 1,0 element from the covariance matrix.

Here:

```
def calculate_correlation(s):
    # if correlation > 0.6 or correlation < 0.6 remove A3
    s = s[['A1','A3']]
    return (s.corr().iloc[1,0])
```